# Netflix Vizceral - remove node when rendering different data sets

Tags: reactjs, netflix

We are using Netflix Vizceral which is written in React and the associated sample app also provided by Netflix. We have added some functionality to allow the user to select different data sets for viewing.  When providing new JSON data sets to the updateData function.  The problem we are having is that for environment A we have data centers 1,2,3.  When the user selects environment B the data centers are 1,2,4.  The user sees datacenters 1,2,3,4,  one of which is invalid.

How do you reset the visualization or explicitly remove a node?

Comment: make many and many attempts before coming to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this locally and it worked as expected.

There was a related bug [fixed](https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral/commit/dea6b2e44447c845af545bf30064de90ec364362) in vizceral@4.3.2. Are you using the latest vizceral-react with vizceral >=4.3.2?

Comment: Thanks.  This resolved the issue with the invalid "node".